# Django get_FOO_Display() for range list choices

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
STATUS_APPROVE, STATUS_REJECT, STATUS_PROC, STATUS_PEND, STATUS_PAID = range(5)

STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (STATUS_APPROVE, 'Approved'),
    (STATUS_REJECT, 'Rejected'),
    (STATUS_PROC, 'Processing'),
    (STATUS_PEND, 'Pending'),
    (STATUS_PAID, 'Paid'),
)

class ExpenseClaim(TimeStampedModel):
    status = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=STATUS_PEND,
                              choices=STATUS_CHOICES, blank=False)

class MileageClaimSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    status = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
```

I cannot work out a way to get foo display for a choice list with range. So the range keys are used to store the point in list. I need the serializer to return the word and not the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this serializer is readonly you can use the source attribute inside a CharField

```
status = serializers.CharField(source='get_status_display')
```

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source

Comment: Unfortunately I need to write to it as well.

Comment: I ended up adding an extra field so i had both. status_text = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source='get_status_display')